# Echo not working in JQuery Ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Below is a code snippet of my PHP file - I am trying to call a PHP function on click of a button. Simple echo is not working - appreciate any help

```
        /* This function saves Add or Make of Model to Database
        */
        $('#addmake-btn').live('click',function(){
            <?php 
                 echo "Not Working";
            ?>
        });

</script>
```

Comment: JS runs (in your case) on the client and php on the server. Did you mean to do 
`$('#addmake-btn').live('click',function(){
            alert(<?php echo "Not Working"; ?>);
        });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you need to know about how client side and server side language works.
server side languages like PHP will execute in server, **you cant execute** them in client side unlike javascript or some other client side language.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#addmake-btn').live('click',function(){
var printVal = "<?php echo "Not Working"; ?>";
document.write(printVal);
});
```